# What are the best practices for creating sqlite queries for the application?

Tags: android-sqlite

I've taken an extremely modular approach to my android application, but the problem that i've come to is how generic can I make my sqlite queries? For example, if i want to do a where clause that satisfies a set of conditions, e.g. greater than, less than, equal to, greater than equal to, less than equal to.

I am used to working from an entity based framework, how LINQ works. 
Can i do this easily or do i have to take the long way round and create a new method to query every time i need to statisfy a certain criteria?

Comment: You can use parameters to look for varying *values* but if the conditional operators themselves vary, or the number of conditions vary, you'll need to (re)construct the correct statement to send to SQLite.  You might perhaps swap out operators in the client-side code that builds the query, or dynamically construct the raw statement client-side.

Answer (score 1):

although i generally don't like it, but for what you are asking for you can use [ormlite for android](http://ormlite.com/). It's nearly, the same as LINQ.